# Using two partial views in the same view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

### Update 2: partialview

```
@model ASD.Models.StatisticsModel
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
{
    <table id="statisticstable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hour</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Order</th>
                <th>Rows</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    </table>
}
```

---

### Update 1

There was a typo on the partialView name. Fixed it and this error appeared:

Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ASDWebPortalMVC.Models.LogModelVM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ASD.Models.StatisticsModel'.

---

I am using @html.RenderPartial to render a partial view.

**LogModelsController.cs - (Connected to LogModel)**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult LogPartialView()
{
    // Some other stuff 
    LogModelVM LMVM = new LogModelVM();
    return PartialView("_LogPartialLayout", LMVM);
}
```

---

Now I want to add another partial view, using a diffrent model (StatisticsModel)

---

**LogLayout.cshtml**

```
@model ASDMVC.Models.LogModelVM

@* This is the working PartialView *@
<div id="log" class="tab">
    <h1>Log</h1>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogPartialView", "LogModelsController",
            new AjaxOptions
   {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       UpdateTargetId = "divLogs"
   }, new
       {
           id = "NewTableId"
       }))
       {
           <p>@Html.TextBox("SearchString",null, new { @placeholder = "Message" })</p>
           if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
           {
               <p>
               @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomer, Model.CustomerList, new { @id = "logdropdownlabel" })
               </p>
           }
               <p><input type="submit" class="standardbutton logsearch" name="submit" value="Search" /></p> 
           }
           <div id="divLogs">
               @RenderBody()
               @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)
               @{Html.RenderPartial("_LogPartialLayout");}
           </div>
       </div>

@* This is the non-working PartialView. *@
<div id="statistics" class="tab">
    <h1>Statistics</h1>
    <div id="statistics">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_StatisticsPartialView");}
    </div>
</div>
```

**StatisticsController.cs (Connected to StatisticsModel)**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public PartialViewResult Statistics(string conn)
 {
     StatisticsModel STM = new StatisticsModel();
     StatisticsDbContext DbContext = new StatisticsDbContext(conn);
     return PartialView("_StatisticsPartialView", STM);
 }
```

I'm rather new to this so any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: The code you have shown does not make sense in relation to the error. `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_StatisticsPartialView"); }` would throw an error because your passing the instance of `LogModelVM` to it but it needs a model which is typeof `StatisticsModel`. And your also using `_StatisticsPartialView` as the layout in `Statistics.cshtml` which makes not sense either.

Comment: Can you show the view for `_StatisticsPartialView.cshtml` (all you have shown is one for `Statistics.cshtml` and I'm not even sure what the relevance of that is in relation to your question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, your point is valid, I think that partial view contains a different model and the main view is sending another model to it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added the partialview now.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Updated post now.

Comment: That new error is as I noted in my previous comment - you need to pass an instance of  `StatisticsModel` to the partial - e.g. `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_StatisticsPartialView", new StatisticsModel()); }` - if you do not specify the model, then it uses the model from the current view which is typeof `LogModelVM` hence the exception

Comment: @ErikSellberg, have a look on my updated answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Now I get this error: The type or namespace name 'StatisticsModel' could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to use the fully qualified name - `new ASD.Models.StatisticsModel()` or add a `@using ASD.Models;` statement at the top of your view

Comment: Thanks! Now it works :) Really appreciate it!

Comment: Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution? @StephenMuecke

Comment: The answer by Kundan Singh Chouhan was almost right and I have now edited it, so you can accept that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get it by defining its full path like below:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_StatisticsPartialView.cshtml")
```

Or Alternately

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_StatisticsPartialView.cshtml"); }
```

Hope this helps !!

Edit: As per the new change you must have to pass the correct model as the currently its getting `LogModelVM` so use instead below:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_StatisticsPartialView", new ASD.Models.StatisticsModel());}
```

Comment: I still get the same error: Additional information: The partial view '~/Views/Shared/_StatisticsPartialView.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

~/Views/Shared/_StatisticsPartialView.cshtml

Comment: @ErikSellberg, can you share your solution explorer screenshot indicating the shared folder in which this view exists?

Comment: Actually there was a typo in the partial view name, will update main post at the top now with the new error.